# Mousehover action In selenium works, But the action is not visible on the browser screen, is there any way that i can see it in REAL

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

My code

```
WebElement menu= bd.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main-nav > div.multi-level-nav.reveal-on-click > div > ul.first-level-ul > li:nth-child(1) > a"));
        actions.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
        System.out.println("mouse hover done");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

It works, but when it comes to the running time on the browser screen the dropdown button is not listed down when doing the mousehover. I practically want to put this into display.

Comment: Please don't ever write anything IN ALL CAPS.

Comment: @JamesZ okay done.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the display of the dropdown button opening up you have to take a [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120087/7429447) at the appropiate time as follows:

```
WebElement menu= bd.findElement(By.cssSelector("#main-nav > div.multi-level-nav.reveal-on-click > div > ul.first-level-ul > li:nth-child(1) > a"));
actions.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshots\\keshu_thilakan.png"));
System.out.println("mouse hover done");
```

Comment: The Screenshot is captured, but no dropdown button is displayed.